# Download excel file in javascript from Rest API response content-disposition outputs [Object, Object]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, download, content-disposition

I want to download a excel file from my angularJs code. Where i made a http post request to Java Rest API and returned the file with header 
"Content-Disposition" : "attachment; filename=\"new_excel_file.xlsx\""

Java Code

```
@Post 
@Path("/excel/trekResult")
@Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")
public Response getResultsReport(@HeaderParam(Constants.ID) Long userId, @QueryParam(Constants.COMPANY_TREK_ID) Integer companyTrekId) {
String CONTENT_DESPOSITION = "Content-Disposition";
String CONTENT_ATTACHEMENT = "attachment; filename=\"new_excel_file.xlsx\"";

//Generates a excel file in local file system
File excelFile = misHelper.writeToFile(workBook, mis, userId, "trek-results");

return Response.ok().entity((Object)excelFile).
    header(CONTENT_DESPOSITION, CONTENT_ATTACHEMENT).build();

}
```

On Javascript Side

```
myService.exportResult($scope.companyTrek.id).then(function(result) {
  if(result !== undefined || result !== '') {
    var blob = new Blob([result], {
      type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    });
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    saveAs(blob, 'Trek-Results-'+fetchCurrentDate()+ '.xlsx');
  }
}
```

Used FileSaver.js to save file.

**The output file is [Object, Object]**

**Tested The locally generated file.**

Here is a similar question for reference that didn't help me.

[receive an excel file as response in javascript from a Rest service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867120/receive-an-excel-file-as-response-in-javascript-from-a-rest-service)

Comment: You need to be more specific, clarifying what the problem is  for people to help you. Can you re-edit your question and append output errors?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed the Mime types are different on Java server vs Angular client.
This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document) shows the different MIME types related to spreadsheets.
Try making them consistent and seeing if that fixed it.
There was also [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648823/return-excel-downloadable-file-from-spring) without mishelper.