# Download excel file in browser using blob

Tags: javascript, node.js, blob, fs

I have a requirement to download an excel file in the browser. I am using nodejs in the back end and plain JavaScript in the front end.

My API endpoint is 'https://callerid-lookup.herokuapp.com/download'

```
/download/excel 


res.status(200);
var path = './report.xlsx';
fs.readFile(path, function (err, data) {
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=report.xlsx');
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
    console.log('server side1', data);
    res.send(data);
});
```

Front end code looks like following

```
 $.get("https://callerid-lookup.herokuapp.com/download", {
    responseType : 'ArrayBuffer'
},
    function (data, status) {
    console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    var blob = new Blob([data], {
            type : 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
        });
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = "report.xlsx";
    link.click();
});
```

I can see the file downloading, but there is only [Object, Object] in the excel file downloaded in the first cell.

I tried giving 'responseType'  as 'arraybuffer/blog' in the http request, but nothing worked for me, help is appreciated

Log file:

client receive data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w46o9gqt7z99bzt/client-response.txt?dl=0

server sending data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xu7nzelbjbmzjwj/server-response.txt?dl=0

**Updated with Sample API endpoint and jquery UI code**

Comment: I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44995154/3103891) would help you out.

Comment: @GalAbra I am using the same mime type in both server and client side

Comment: Could you please provide some kind of a way to test it out? Or just print `JSON.stringify(response)` for example

Comment: @GalAbra Log is very long, so attached it as a file and upadted my question can you check.

Comment: Is what you've added the output of `JSON.stringify(response)`?!

Comment: client side yes console.log('client Response', JSON.stringify(response));
server side  console.log('server side', data); @GalAbra

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196073/discussion-between-dibish-and-galabra).